# How do I read a text file having Unicode codes?

Tags: c++, file, ubuntu, file-io, utf

I initialize a string using the following code.

```
  std::string unicode8String = "\u00C1 M\u00F3ti S\u00F3l";
```

Printing it using `cout`, the output is *Á Móti Sól*.

But when I read same same string from a text file using `ifstream`, store it in a `std::string`, and print it, the output is *\u00C1 M\u00F3ti S\u00F3l*.

The content of my file is *\u00C1 M\u00F3ti S\u00F3l* and I want to print it as *Á Móti Sól*. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I'm sure that's been asked before.  Did you search?

Comment: There are no UTF codes in your question. If you want to convert the six character string \u00C1 to the character with value 0xC1 then you have to write the code to parse the string. There's no quick answer. But since you are confused about what you are doing I think you probably really want to do something else. Very hard to say what though.

Comment: yes, I searched but could not find the solution.

Comment: @john What I want to do is : example : The text file I have : \u00C1 M\u00F3ti S\u00F3l And I want my program to read it and print Á Móti Sól. Is there any function for this ?

Comment: @Anubha No, but you can write your own, see my answer.

Comment: @Anubha If you actually have \u in your file, remove it. You might write a file first, to see how it should look like.

Comment: @DieterLücking what would removing the \u accomplish ?

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head (completely untested)

```
std::string convert_string(const std::string& in)
{
    std::string out;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < in.size(); )
    {
        if (i + 5 < in.size() && in[i] == '\\' && in[i+1] == 'u' && 
            in[i+2] == '0' && in[i+3] == '0' && 
            isxdigit(in[i+4]) && isxdigit(in[i+5]))
        {
            out += (unsigned char)16*in[i+4] + (unsigned char)in[i+5];
            i += 6;
        }
        else
        {
            out += in[i];
            ++i;
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

But this won't work with any unicode values above 255, (e.g. \u1234) because you have the fundamental problem that your string stores 8 bit characters, and Unicode characters can have up to 20 bits.

As I said completely untested, but I'm sure you get the idea.

Comment: So I have to write a function myself ? As I understand \u00C1 is Á, and \u00F3 is ó and so on...So this are Unicode Characters, so does not any pre-existing function/library exits for this ?

Comment: You two will need to decide if those unicode escape characters are in the string or not.  John is assuming so, and you seem unsure.

Comment: the txt file contains \u00C1 M\u00F3ti S\u00F3l, so when I read it into a string the string has "\u00C1 M\u00F3ti S\u00F3l"

Comment: @Anubha, answer this question, it will make a lot less confusion. How long is the string "\u00C1" you have in your *file*, six characters or one character?

Comment: six characters in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try printing using "`std::wcout`"!

Answer (score 0):

The unicode characters have a different representation in a text file (There is no \u).

**For Evaluation**

```
int main()
{
    // Write
    {
        std::string s = "\u00C1 M\u00F3ti S\u00F3l";
        std::ofstream out("/tmp/test.txt");
        out << s;
    }
    // Read Text
    {
        std::string s;
        std::ifstream in("/tmp/test.txt");
        std::getline(in, s);
        std::cout << "Result: " << s << std::endl;
    }
    // Read Binary
    {
        std::ifstream in("/tmp/test.txt");
        in.unsetf(std::ios_base::skipws);
        std::istream_iterator<unsigned char> first(in);
        std::istream_iterator<unsigned char> last;
        std::vector<unsigned char> v(first, last);
        std::cout << "Result: ";
        for(unsigned c: v) std::cout << std::hex << c << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

On Linux with UTF8:
Result: Á Móti Sól
Result: c3 81 20 4d c3 b3 74 69 20 53 c3 b3 6c

Comment: what I meant was that the file was not in UTF8 format, the file literally had the string "\u00C1 M\u00F3ti S\u00F3l" and not Á Móti Sól. With your write the file contains Á Móti Sól to begin with.